# My css file is not being found by the browser despite giving the absolute path in the html file

Tags: html, css

CSS code

```
.headi {
font-size: 4em;
}
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Organicking</title>
  <link href="‪‪C:\Users\01Var\Desktop\organicking\fanandcool.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
</head>
<body>
  <a href="C:\Users\01Var\Desktop\organicking\organicking.html">
    <img src="C:\Users\01Var\Downloads\realistic-tomato-isolated\6146.jpg" 
style="width:100px;height:100px;" border = "2" align = "left" />
</a>

<h1 class="headi">Organicking</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

ERROR message

```
%E2%80%AA%E2%80%AAC:/Users/01Var/Desktop/organicking/fanandcool.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

On opening the file in browser
"Your file was not found" is what i see, and the location of the file showing in the browser URL field is

```
file:///C:/Users/01Var/Desktop/%E2%80%AA%E2%80%AAC:/Users/01Var/Desktop/organicking/fanandcool.css
```

Comment: set href path relative to your html file path

Comment: The file still cannot be found: 

fanandcool.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely at the error message you can see `%E2%80%AA%E2%80%AA` in front of the URL.

`%E2%80%AA` is the URL encoded Unicode `U+202A` which stands for `Left-to-Right Embedding (LRE)` and is an invisible character controlling the write direction.

And that invisible character breaks the URL resolving.

Depending on the editor you might be able to display those invisible chars.

And if not then you might be able to get rid of it if you select `"‪‪C` in `href="‪‪C:\Users\01Var` and then manually type `"C` again.

Besides that: URLs use `/` and not `\` as path separators, and local URLs have to start with `file:///`, so your absolute path as to be `file:///C:/Users/01Var/Desktop/organicking/fanandcool.css`

Comment: So, in your opinion, what should have been done to be able to use the absolute path?

Comment: @VarunKhanna you need to get rid of the LRE. How depends on the editor and OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the css and html files in the same folder and then you must only specify the name of the css file in html code.

```
<link href="‪‪fanandcool.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css"  />
```

Comment: Not working: fanandcool.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: When you view your page source in the browser and click on css file link, the browser views it?

Answer (score 1):

It is showing that your file does not exist or the Given path is wrong.

there can be two possibilities use "/" forward slash instead of backward because it is a relative path or you don't need to provide the whole path if you are in the same folder where your css folder is just do this.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fanandcool.css">
```

Comment: file:///C:/Users/01Var/Desktop/%E2%80%AA%E2%80%AAcss/fanandcool.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

Add a relative path as:

```
<link href="\fanandcool.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

Comment: Again, the file cannot be found: 

fanandcool.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate folder for your CSS file like "style" and then add path to html file like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new folder in the "organicking" folder with name "style" and the css file inside of the "style" folder, and did not mention any folder in the path. I simply did so: link href="fanandcool.css"

And, it has worked!